# MVC 3 Razor Dropdown Change Simple Javascript

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, jquery-events

I have an MVC3 Razor application which I'm trying to execute simple Javascript on a dropdown list change.

My view uses a custom helper which return the proper object depending on the data type (dropdown list for enumerated lists, radio buttons for binaries, etc.)

The following helper:

```
@Html.RecipeEditorFor(model => model.Coating_Mode)
```

which renders the following selectlist in html:

```
<div class="form-line">
    <div class="editor-field">
        <select id="Coating_Mode" name="Coating_Mode">
             <option value="1">Adhesive</option>
             <option selected="selected" value="2">SR</option>
             <option value="3">Inspection</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to have a simple Javascript execute whenever the value of the select list is changed:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#Coating_Mode').change(function () {
        alert("hello");
    }); 
</script>
```

I will gladly provide any other code as needed to help answer the problem...

Comment: Does your script run after the DOM is loaded?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/HVMKU/ well can you specify your problem a little bit more? the code you provided works great or i have misunderstood something important.

Comment: You are missing the '$(document).ready(function()'

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the script to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#Coating_Mode').change(function () {
            alert("hello");
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

Also, I would advise against using an id in the selector if you intend to use this in a html helper.  Use a class selector instead in case more than one item requires it.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to get back to you but this worked!  If I had the ability to mark it as an anwer i would.

Comment: @user988148 No worries :-) You should be able to click the tick on the left to accept it as the answer?

Comment: i dont have a 15 reputation... dont know what it takes to get there - guess this rookie needs to give you experts some answers.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your script is running before the DOM has finished loading - ie, the script is placed before your helper.

It's good practice to wrap any javascript events inside a [document ready event](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).  Then the script can be placed anywhere (although in the head or right before `</body>` are most appropriate).

So, change your script to this and it should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // This function won't fire until the DOM is completely loaded.
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#Coating_Mode').change(function () {
            alert("hello");
        }); 

    });
</script>
```